# Table in two column mode

Tags: tables, two-column, elsarticle

I am writng a paper with the `elsarticle` class and I want to span a table in the two column mode over the whole textwidth (so to say interrupt the two column mode for the table, and afterwards continue with the one column mode).

I would like to wrap the text around, however the table always moves to the middle of the next page.

I scanned the internet, but I did not manage to solve my problem. I just want to include a table at a certain point, and when I type text before that table, it should be filled on both 2 columns before on that page and if I write text behind that table it should appear within the two columns afterwards.

I would be very thankful for any help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,3p,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5] %Show line numbers

% Added packages
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/} }
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
% Added packages

\begin{document}

Some text, tables, figures etc.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try the `strip` environment (`cuted` package), which interrupts the two-column mode to insert whatever you want?

Answer (score 1):

`table*` is working fine, as you are not provided any `MWE`, I've taken my own, please refer the tags:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\begin{table*}
\caption{System variables dependencies}\label{tab2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X *{5}{Y} @{}}
\toprule
System variables & $o_{v}$ & $s_{p}$ & $t_{m}$ & $l_{ft}$ & $l_{ot}$\\
\cmidrule(l){2-2} \cmidrule(l){3-3} \cmidrule(l){4-4} 
\cmidrule(l){5-5} \cmidrule(l){6-6}
\addlinespace
Subsystem associated & V & Pr & M & $\textrm{T}_\textrm{1}$ & 
$\textrm{T}_  \textrm{2}$ \\
\addlinespace
Mathematical dependencies & & & $t_{m}(t)=23-0.25
\times  o_{v}(t)+0.62\times s_{p}(t)$
& $l_{ft}(t)=l_{ft}(t-1) -0.001\times s_{p}(t)$
& $l_{ft}(t)=l_{ft}(t-1) -0.0005\times s_{p}(t)$ \\
\addlinespace
Operational dependencies & $o_{v}(t)=0$ if $s_{p}(t)=0$ & & 
& $l_{ft}(t)=l_{ft}(t-1)$ if $s_{p}(t)=0$
& $l_{ot}(t)=l_{ot}(t-1)$ if $s_{p}(t)=0$ \\
\addlinespace
Nominal value range 
& $0\rightarrow100$ (\%) 
& $0\rightarrow100$ (\%)
& $23\rightarrow83$ (°C)
& $2\rightarrow100$ (\%)
& $2\rightarrow100$ (\%)\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{midfloat}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8]

\begin{strip}%[]
\renewcommand\captionfont{\footnotesize}%
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X *{5}{Y} @{}}
\toprule
System variables & $o_{v}$ & $s_{p}$ & $t_{m}$ & $l_{ft}$ & $l_{ot}$\\
\cmidrule(l){2-2} \cmidrule(l){3-3} \cmidrule(l){4-4} 
\cmidrule(l){5-5} \cmidrule(l){6-6}
\addlinespace
Subsystem associated & V & Pr & M & $\textrm{T}_\textrm{1}$ & 
$\textrm{T}_  \textrm{2}$ \\
\addlinespace
Mathematical dependencies & & & $t_{m}(t)=23-0.25
\times  o_{v}(t)+0.62\times s_{p}(t)$
& $l_{ft}(t)=l_{ft}(t-1) -0.001\times s_{p}(t)$
& $l_{ft}(t)=l_{ft}(t-1) -0.0005\times s_{p}(t)$ \\
\addlinespace
Operational dependencies & $o_{v}(t)=0$ if $s_{p}(t)=0$ & & 
& $l_{ft}(t)=l_{ft}(t-1)$ if $s_{p}(t)=0$
& $l_{ot}(t)=l_{ot}(t-1)$ if $s_{p}(t)=0$ \\
\addlinespace
Nominal value range 
& $0\rightarrow100$ (\%) 
& $0\rightarrow100$ (\%)
& $23\rightarrow83$ (°C)
& $2\rightarrow100$ (\%)
& $2\rightarrow100$ (\%)\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\captionof{table}{System variables dependencies\label{tab2}}
\end{strip}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your code part, but still the table is placed on the next side, and not exactly where I want it to be.

Comment: @Niklas May I know what you meant by `next side`?

Comment: I have included a relevant code part now. With next side I mean, the table is displayed on a new, next page. I would like to achieve a result like Simon Dispa has shown.

Comment: It looks like its not possible: https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-widefigs

Comment: @Niklas Please try with the updated `MWE`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little example will guide you. Using `multicol` you can start with two columns, stop the two columns environment, insert a wide table or a figure in the place you want, and then continue with two columns, or one column if you wish so.

I might want to comment the `\begin{multicols}{2}` and  `\end{multicols}` and use the twocolumn `elsearticle` option to see what happens with a float.

But if you want to send a paper to  Elsevier's journals you should comply with their instructions for the preparation of a   2-column format camera-ready paper in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[1p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{tabularx} % specify table width

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \section{Introduction}
    1-2 \kant[1-2]
    \section{Method}    
    3.5.    \kant[3-5]
\end{multicols}

\begin{table*}[htb]
    \caption{The next-to-leading order  results*.}
    \label{table:1}
    \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{2pc} % enlarge column spacing
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % enlarge line spacing
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}
            \hline
            Nascetur &
            Ridiculus ut mus. Quisque sem. Lorem ipsum dolor
            sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Cras placerat dapibus
            enim. Duis aliquam magna at dui. \\
            \hline
            Enean &
            Tincidunt ipsum tincidunt felis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad
            litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymen\ae{}os.
            Nunc auctor. Etiam faucibus nulla eu dolor. Nam vestibulum risus
            ut est. \\
            \hline
            Sed &
            Semper, tellus lobortis tempor euismod, nunc massa sagittis
            enim, a accumsan sapien enim ut nisi.  Cras rutrum dignissim
            libero. \\
            \hline
    \end{tabularx}\\[5pt]
    (*) The experimental values are given in ref.
\end{table*}

\begin{multicols}{2}  
    11-12. \kant[11-12]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: tx]

**UPDATE** Without using `multicol` this is another possibility.

```
\documentclass[3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{tabularx} % specify table width
\usepackage[small, tableposition=top]{caption}  
\usepackage{cuted}  

\begin{document}

    \section{Introduction}
    1-2 \kant[1-2]
    \section{Method}    
    3.5.    \kant[3-5]

\subsection{Tables}

Tables should be presented in the form shown in
Table~\ref{table:1}.  Their layout should be consistent
throughout.

\begin{strip}
   \captionof{table}{The next-to-leading order  results*.}
    \label{table:1}
    \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{2pc} % enlarge column spacing
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % enlarge line spacing
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}
            \hline
            Nascetur &
            Ridiculus ut mus. Quisque sem. Lorem ipsum dolor
            sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Cras placerat dapibus
            enim. Duis aliquam magna at dui. \\
            \hline
            Enean &
            Tincidunt ipsum tincidunt felis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad
            litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymen\ae{}os.
            Nunc auctor. Etiam faucibus nulla eu dolor. Nam vestibulum risus
            ut est. \\
            \hline
            Sed &
            Semper, tellus lobortis tempor euismod, nunc massa sagittis
            enim, a accumsan sapien enim ut nisi.  Cras rutrum dignissim
            libero. \\
            \hline
    \end{tabularx}\\[5pt]
    (*) The experimental values are given in ref.
\end{strip}

\section{Results}
    11-12. \kant[11-12]
\end{document}
```

[image: N2]

The environment `strip` puts a `\vbox{⟨wide onecolumn material⟩}` in full-width on double-column page.

Comment: That looks like I would like to have it. But for acception at elsevier I think I need to get it somehow without multicol...

Comment: @Niklas  OK. I updated the answer.